# Running a docker logs command in background remotely over ssh

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, nohup

We have a use case where the docker remote execution is seperately executed on another server.

so users login to server A and submt an ssh command which runs a script on remote server B.

The script performs several docker commands like prune,build,run which are working fine.

I have this command at the end of the script which is supposed to write the docker logs in background to an efs file system which is mounted on both
servers A and B.This way users can access the logfile from server A without actually logging into server B (to prevent access to containers).

I have tried all available solutions related to this and nothing seems to be working for running a process in background remotely.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
The below code is the script on remote server.user calls this script from server A over ssh like ssh id@serverB-IP docker_script.sh

```
loc=${args[0]}
cd $loc

# Set parameters
imagename=${args[1]}
port=${args[2]}
desired_port=${args[3]}

docker stop $imagename && sleep 10 || true
docker build -t $imagename $loc |& tee build.log
docker system prune -f
port_config=$([[ -z "${port}" ]] && echo '' || echo -p $desired_port:$port)
docker run -d --rm --name $imagename $port_config $imagename
sleep 10
docker_gen_log $loc $imagename
echo ""
echo "Docker build and run are now complete ....Please refer to the logs under $loc/build.log $loc/run.log"
}
docker_gen_log(){
    loc=${args[0]}
    cd $loc
    imagename=${args[1]}
    docker logs -f $imagename &> run.log &
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only running a single container like you show, you can just run it in the foreground.  The container logs will go to the `docker run` stdout/stderr and you can collect them normally.

```sh
docker run --rm --name "$imagename" $port_config "$imagename" \
  > "$loc/run.log" 2>&1
# also note no `-d` option
echo ""
echo "Docker build and run are now complete ....Please refer to the logs under $loc/build.log $loc/run.log"
```

If you have multiple containers, or if you want the container to keep running if the script disconnects, you can collect logs at any point until the container is removed.  For this sort of setup you'd want to explicitly `docker rm` the container.

```sh
docker run -d --name "$imagename" $port_config "$imagename"
# note, no --rm option

docker wait "$imagename" # actually container name
docker logs "$imagename" >"$loc/run.log" 2>&1
docker rm "$imagename"
```

This latter approach won't give you incremental logs while the container is running.  Given that your script seems to assume the container will be finished within 10 seconds that's probably not a concern for you.

Comment: Thanks David for the response... Ours is a platform where multiple users simulatenously execute this script..Also we want the script to be running even after the ssh disconnects...so that is the reason I wanted the docker logs to run in background ..but for some reason it is not running as expected.